# MongoDb Polygon Search Query returns no result

Tags: java, mongodb, geometry, geospatial, boundbox

I have problems regarding a Polygone Search in my MongoDB.

I have a document structure like:

```
Object:{id,type,...,
    data:{
    name,
    loc:{
    lng:xxx
    lat:yyy
    type:Point}}}
```

I have an 2d Index on "data.loc".

My query in java code is:

```
DBCollection coll = database.getCollection(type);

    BasicDBList points = new BasicDBList();
    points.add(bbox.getNe());
    points.add(bbox.getSe());
    points.add(bbox.getSw());
    points.add(bbox.getNw());
    points.add(bbox.getNe());
    BasicDBList parentList = new BasicDBList();
    parentList.add(points);

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("data.loc",
            new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin",
                    new BasicDBObject("$geometry", new BasicDBObject("type","Polygon")
                            .append("coordinates", parentList))));
```

The Debuger tells me that the query is for example

> { "data.loc" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Polygon" ,
>   "coordinates" : [ [ [ 48.240553 , 16.451597] , [ 48.162751 ,
>   16.451597] , [ 48.162751 , 16.303968] , [ 48.240553 , 16.303968] , [ 48.240553 , 16.451597]]]}}}}

But after typing

```
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);

 try {
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            data.add(cursor.next().get("data"));
        }
 } finally {
        cursor.close();
 }

    return data;´
```

data is allways null.

Can anyone find any problems in my approach or does maybe someone have a better approach? In fact I want to do a boundingbox search on my database.

Thank you for your help!
Best regards
Daniel

Comment: Can you give an example of one of your documents that you expect to be found by the geo query? Also, to clarify, it's a 2d index and not a 2d sphere index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the Java MongoDB driver query for the points in the polygone for a GeoJson strcuture like this is

```
  BasicDBList points = new BasicDBList();
    points.add(bbox.getNe());
    points.add(bbox.getSe());
    points.add(bbox.getSw());
    points.add(bbox.getNw());
    points.add(bbox.getNe());
    BasicDBList parentList = new BasicDBList();
    parentList.add(points);

    Set<Object> data = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<Object>();

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("geometry",
            new BasicDBObject("$geoWithin",
                    new BasicDBObject("$geometry", new BasicDBObject("type","Polygon")
                            .append("coordinates", parentList))));
    System.err.println(query);
```